# Can multiple generalized eigenvectors of higher rank get mapped to the same generalized eigenvector of lower rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, generalized-eigenvector

I'm reading [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Overview_and_definition) for generalized eigenvectors, and I'm stuck on one part:

They show in [the canonical basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Canonical_basis) section that (assuming a fixed eigenvalue $\lambda$ for the whole post), $\rho_k$, the number of linearly independent generalized eigenvectors of rank $k$, can be found by looking at the difference in ranks for adjacent powers of $(A - \lambda I)$:

$\rho_k = \text{rank}[(A - \lambda I)^{k-1}] - \text{rank}[(A - \lambda I)^k]$

I understand $\text{rank}[(A - \lambda I)^k]$ as looking at the dimension of the nullspace of $(A - \lambda I)^k$, so looking at that difference tells you how many generalized eigenvectors need $k$ (and not fewer) applications of $(A - \lambda I)$ to be mapped all the way to zero, which is the definition of a generalized eigenvector of rank $k$.

A generalized eigenvector of rank $k$ generates a Jordan Chain, by producing a generalized vector of rank $k - 1$ with each extra application of $(A - \lambda I)$, as they mention in the intro. And, that chain should all be linearly independent.

**My question is:** is it possible to have two generalized eigenvectors of rank $k$ both get mapped to the same generalized eigenvector of rank $k - 1$ by applying $(A - \lambda I)$ ? i.e., is it possible for the chains to "merge" ?

E.g., if $x$ is a generalized eigenvector of rank $k-1$ and $y_1 \neq y_2$ are generalized eigenvectors of rank $k$, is it possible to have:

$(A - \lambda I) y_1 = x$ **and** $(A - \lambda I) y_2 = x$ ?

My guess is no, because that implies that
$(A - \lambda I) (y_1 - y_2) = 0$,
which would mean that $(y_1 - y_2)$ is itself a generalized eigenvector of rank $1$, but I can't figure out how to see that intuitively.

Comment: Consider, say, $(x,y)\mapsto(y,0)$ with $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$.